# Is there an amd graphics installed on my Ubuntu?

Tags: amd-graphics

I just installed Linux Ubuntu version 20.04
But I don't think the amd graphics card is installed!
How do I check if the graphics card is installed?
Graphics card model:
AMD RADEON R5 M320 2GB
The amd site for my graphics is not a Linux version!
I'm sorry if my English is bad

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 5500
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230 / R7 M260DX / Radeon 520 Mobile] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Jet PRO [Radeon R5 M230 / R7 M260DX / Radeon 520 Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

Is my graphics card installed here? it's true ? So why install another graphics model? is it possible ?

Comment: You can also comment your question and my answer. I added some more information to the answer.

Comment: Thanks
Isn't it just a problem that the original graphics card model is different from the installation?

Comment: What do you mean? These numbers don't mean much. They are variants. All looks well to me. What is your concern?

Comment: thank you
I have another problem! How do I change the shit + alt language to shift + ctrl right?

Comment: Please ask another question for a new problem. You can also consider accepting my answer by clicking the check sign at the left of it if it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have an AMD graphics adapter and it is working.

You can also check by

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

You have dual graphics with two adapters: Intel and AMD.

You can run applications with either of these.